# Cakephp: get youTube playlist as json and send data to view

Tags: xml, json, cakephp, youtube

I would like to call data from my youtube playlist. As far as I can see, the return is json.
What would be the best way to call the data into the controller?

I tried

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/myid?&v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
$result = Set::reverse(json_decode(file_get_contents($url)));
```

but it returns me this error:
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

If I try it with jquery

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/myid?&v=2&alt=json&callback=?',function(data) {
```

I get a result in data and work with it.

What is the correct way to retrieve the json data the "cake" way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of cakephp are you using?

This is for 2.x and should work

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
$this->Http = new HttpSocket();
$_result = $this->Http->get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/myid?&v=2');
pr(Set::reverse(json_decode($_result)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Jujst by posting I found out the solution:

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/myid?&v=2';
    $result = Set::reverse(Xml::build($url));
    debug($result);
```

There is no need for json :-)
Just call the xml feedback and push it into an array and do what you want :-)